# Using large number of videos in android application

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to use videos in my android application. There are 80 videos (total size 700MB), so how will I use them in android application?

What will I have to do if I want to use videos with total size as mentioned above?

- Where I need to store large video files in android?
- In Listview one item 10 videos I want to show these videos in GridView.
- I want to read 10 video for one item in my LIstView like each item 10 videos I want to read in my application.
- It's a stand alone application we are not using server for reading the videos.

Please suggest me are any examples link provide me.

Comment: What is so bad about server anyway? They're cheap nowadays and IMO they're the best and probably only considerable option.

Answer (score 1):

**Nobody want to download application with 700MB**. For better performance and standard application flow, its better to use server to store those videos (I knew you mentioned you don't want to use server).

**Update:** Also when you store those videos on device then possible problem of memory issues. Where to store those videos in external storage if its not present then internal and what's the available size of those storage..

Comment: i am getting confusion about where i need to store videos file in SD Card(memory card)?- 1 video file is 10mb around 70 video files are there please suggest me.

Comment: To keep those video files in your application you need to use application package directory /asset, and then you have to copy those files to copy into sdcard, but when you store those files in asset then your application's .apk file become larger around 700mb and no one user want to download this large sized application.

Comment: this is client side application we are not introducing in market. if i keep 70 videos in asset/raw folder in my application, the application will not slow?

Comment: Do you know the maximum size of .apk file?